# Why cloud endpoints dashboard is never getting updated with 'request' metrics?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-kubernetes-engine

I setup cloud endpoints on GKE. I enabled JWT Auth with google service accounts.
API is working fine. It needs the JWT passed in Authentication header. It doesn't allow expired JWT all are working as expected. Except the dashboard on GCP shows nothing. It shows 0 requests. 0 requests/s.

I tried to check logs on stackdriver. It's empty :(

Apparently i need 10 reputations to show this image embedded in the question. Sorry for inconvenience 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iooO8.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Started to work after enabling the Google Cloud Endpoints API in the API console